# How an Ethereum ledger stores data and how to access it in smart contracts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am new to blockchain. I have watched various videos on ethereum and smart contracts but i don't understand what exactly is stored in Ledger. All smart contract examples i looked at created a `mapping` in the smart contract is that it or am i missing something ?
I also read about miners, miners executes smart contracts but what do they validate?

Comment: I recommend you to start from blockchain basics. you can start with bitcoin blockchain for understanding things like block structure, transactions, miners, double spending, cryptography, smartcontracts,  and distributed approach then you can jump to ethereum and hyperledger frameworks.